# How to access text contents of file returned by a "file" or "allFiles" GraphQL query in Gatsby?

Tags: file, graphql, gatsby

I'm trying to access the contents of a text file returned by a "file" GraphQL query in Gatsby (via the gatsby-source-filesystem plugin). The query is definitely returning a File node. The problem is that I'm expecting the internal>contents field to contain the contents of the file, but it does not; it's always null. Here an example query and result, as obtained using Gatsby's GraphiQL browser. The question is (1) what am I doing wrong, and (2) what should I do to achieve my intent of accessing the file contents?

Query

```
query MyQuery {
  file(ext: {eq: ".lean"}, name: {eq: "test"}) {
    name
    relativePath
    size
    internal {
      content
      mediaType
    }
  }
}
```

Result

```
{
  "data": {
    "file": {
      "name": "test",
      "relativePath": "test.lean",
      "size": 10,
      "internal": {
        "content": null,
        "mediaType": "application/octet-stream"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see from the result, the file isn't empty (the file has one short line of Lean Prover code inside), but the value of the internal>content field is nevertheless null. I'm obviously doing something wrong, but after an hour of trying to figure out what, I figure someone else might also benefit from a quick answer. Thanks for shedding light on my issue.

Comment: were you able to solve it? I'm running into the same issue. Would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 5):

Ok, so gatsby-source-filesystem actually exports a helper method, loadNodeContents (which of course just reads from the file). The only problem is that this is not documented on the public docs site for this plugin. Here's the file where the relevant code appears.
 https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/blob/master/packages/gatsby-source-filesystem/src/index.js

Comment: Sorry to be talking to myself here, but it looks like the function above doesn't work. Basic problem seems to be that fs isn't available on client side. Still looking.

Comment: Ok, yet another comment. The problem/issue is that the file system (fs) isn't available to most of the code one writes in Gatsby, because that code will run from some directory in an S3 bucket or something. The fs is only available at website *build* time. The trick, then, is that fs is available in the gatsby-node.js file. Content can be fetched there and attached as an auxiliary field to the File nodes retrieved by a "file" or "allFiles" query. To do this, one implements onNodeCreate. The auxiliary field, "fields.content" can the be used in a the query and to return content to the client.